# ImmutableJS not working with new custom object instance

Tags: javascript, constructor, immutability, immutable.js

Using `Immutable.fromJS()` on a raw JS object works as expected and returns a Map, but trying to do just the same `Immutable.fromJS()` with a custom object obtained from a constructor function **does not** work.

Meaning:

- `{/*1*/}`: `console.log` returns custom object.
- `{/*2*/}`: `console.log` returns **the same** custom object, even though I used `Immutable.fromJS()`.
- `{/*3*/}`: `console.log` returns custom object.
- `{/*4*/}`: `console.log` returns `map = Immutable.fromJS()`, as expected.

I can't find any explanation in the documentation.

```
{/*EXPORTING CONSTRUCTOR*/}
export function MyObject() {
  this.id = null;
  this.name = '';
}

{/*EXPORTING RAW OBJECT*/}
export my_object = {
  this.id = null;
  this.name = '';
}

//in another file
//importing, and than:

let myConstructedObject = new MyObject();
let myRawObject = my_object;

{/*1*/} console.log(myConstructedObject) // => object
{/*2*/} console.log(Immutable.fromJS(myConstructedObject)) // => object ?!?!

{/*3*/} console.log(myRawObject) // => object
{/*4*/} console.log(Immutable.fromJS(myRawObject)) // => map (OK!)
```

Comment: You can try Immutable.fromJS(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myConstructedObject))), if you don't care about the performance.

Comment: I do care, both about performance and readability ; ) so thanks for suggestions but I would rather not use the above approach. 
Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that people in this topic: [How do I make a custom immutable type using facebook/immutable-js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816069/how-do-i-make-a-custom-immutable-type-using-facebook-immutable-js) actually discuss the same problem from a constructive point.

Summing up that discussion, you cannot just "Immutivize" a custom object, but you can write an immutable object on your own, using either Immutable.Record (with pure ImmutableJS) or Map (using 'extendable-immutable' library.)